# Coffeescript: Better way of dealing with instance class methods

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to access instance variables from within a nested object ('action'). The only workaround I could find was using a local var ('_') to represent the parent object.

```
Class Mover
...
Constructor () => 
    _ = this
    @mode = "wave"
    @action= {

        wave: ->
            _.x = _.ox  
            _.y = _.oy = Math.cos(window.G.time * _.speed + _.c + _.vary) * _.amp - _.amp * .5
            return

        jump: ->
            _.y = _.oy = Math.min(0,Math.cos(window.G.time*_.speed + _.c * _.vary)) * _.amp - _.amp * .5
            _.x = _.ox
            return

    @loop =>
        @action[@mode]()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a fat arrow (=>) inside your action object like so:

```
wave: =>
    @x = @ox  
    @y = @oy = Math.cos(window.G.time * @speed + @c + @vary) * @amp - @amp * .5
    return
```